# Can a hacker surpass internet http rest calls from desktop application?

Tags: c#, rest, security, rest-security

I have made a desktop software in C# and i am going to make a 30 day free trail of the software ,now i will check the date and time from some server to check the date ... My question is, can the hacker hack this and produce somekind of key or steps to make it full version or produce some crack of it in the market for everyone(I know that a hacker can hack any product )???

Comment: Yes, easily. Search Stackoverflow for "capture http request" and you will find loads of questions.

Comment: To do what you suggest: 2 minutes with fiddler, and a custom "hosts" file entry: done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a hacker can figure out what you are checking a date by REST API, by the monitoring of http traffic, then change the DNS name of your API to local host locally and provide you fake REST API response.

Comment: Yes, he can produce script or program to make it and then sell it in the market.

Comment: so all the android apps are insecure if someone installs a program??

Answer (score 1):

Sure, any software running on the desktop can be decompiled or reverse engineered. Then a patch can be created to disable any security features you've build into the application.

But this requires a lot of work. Not many applications are valuable enough for some hacker to spend so much time on it.

As others have already replied, it's trivially easy to intercept http(s) requests made to a server. Why don't you just use the date/time from the machine/device itself? Not many people will be willing to live with a date set back on their machine just to run your software illegally.

The real problem is where do you store that date. The first time the user legitimately installs your trail, that date won't be present. What is to prevent users from deleting that date and starting the trail period over?

To protect yourself from all this, run (parts of) your software in the cloud. But in that case, you'll need an authentication mechanism for your users.

Comment: do people get pissed off when there application checks time from....everytime on every run because now a days internet is so common..